# record kinect bag file, reconstruct disparity topic

Tags: kinect, openni, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have followed following tutorial [0] to record Kinect data efficiently. It reconstructs the /camera/depth_registered/points topic properly but I also need the topic /camera/depth_registered/disparity. Is it possible to reconstruct this topic from the raw topics, or do I have to record it explicitly?

Cheers,

Oier

[0] http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67173/record-kinect-bag-file,-reconstruct-disparity-topic/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can edit the launch file **openni.launch** by yourself, and remap the topic name you like

---

Originally posted by [bluking](https://answers.ros.org/users/24456/bluking/) with karma: 31 on 2016-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0